# Software Center not opening (whitescreen)

Tags: software-center

I tried to open software center to download Adobe (I recently downloaded ubuntu) but its just a white screen... I tried launching it from Terminal using the code

```
software-center
```

and got back

```
(software-center:31802): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Keep in mind, I don't know how to code so I have no idea whats going on...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

in your terminal with CTRL+ALT+T

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot to say that I already tried that and it gave back      E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: do this `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock` then try again.be careful.